# custom jquery mobile download missing icons

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I put together a custom jquery mobile, and I've downloaded the images from jquery.  I've put the images folder in the content folder within my application, but I can only get the icons to work if I use the cdn link -

with my custom download - the icons don't appear.

Is there somewhere I have to point to the icons or possible use the fully string for the icon rather than just - ex. data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d"

This has been driving me crazy all morning - any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us the relevant code you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the custom download builder does not provide icon set, neither svg, not png.

you can put the required svg icons and their fallback png icons as per your requirement from cdn in your css file.

Add following lines of css in your custom css file for using carat icons in your collapsible lists(i guess).

```
        .ui-icon-carat-u:after {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859-1%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%22%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%2214px%22%20height%3D%2214px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2014%2014%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%2014%2014%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20points%3D%222.051%2C10.596%207%2C5.646%2011.95%2C10.596%2014.07%2C8.475%207%2C1.404%20-0.071%2C8.475%20%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
        }
        .ui-nosvg .ui-icon-carat-u:after {
            background-image: url(images/icons-png/carat-u-white.png);
        }
        .ui-icon-carat-d:after {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859-1%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%22%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%2214px%22%20height%3D%2214px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2014%2014%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%2014%2014%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20style%3D%22fill%3A%23FFFFFF%3B%22%20points%3D%2211.949%2C3.404%207%2C8.354%202.05%2C3.404%20-0.071%2C5.525%207%2C12.596%2014.07%2C5.525%20%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
        }
        .ui-nosvg .ui-icon-carat-d:after {
            background-image: url(images/icons-png/carat-d-white.png);
        }
```

Change the png icons paths accordingly, svg icons are inline.
hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks vinay, I just copied the whole list of svg and png icons from the cdn link, and then put the images folder in my application.  Thanks for your help.